# joined report setup

Tags: joined-reports

In my data model I have the opportunity object with a lookup to a custom object called tenant.

I have another custom object called subs that also has a lookup to tenant.

How can I create a report that for each opportunity it will list information from the subs where it has the tenant in common?

I've tried creating a joined report with the following report types but have had no luck

- Opportunities and tenant
- Tenant with subs

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create 2 custom report types:

1. Tenant with Subs
2. Tenant with Opportunities

This will let you use the parent Tenant Id or Name if unique to join to 2 reports together.

Comment: That worked perfectly - Thanks!  Is there a way to limit the results of one block to where it has a common record?

Comment: I was trying to think of an easy way to do that but off the top of my head I haven't been able to at least not without some type of not out of the box intervention.